# Wordpress admin so slow related to theme

Tags: wordpress, performance, themes, admin

My configuration
- WordPress Version : 3.5.1
- PHP/MySQL Version : 5.3
- Theme : Sterling
- Plugins : Seo Yoast ; BackWPup ; BulletProof Security ; Google Analytics for WordPress ;     LayerSlider WP
- Host : OVH
- url : www.avoirunsite.com

Admin takes 40 sec to load.

I use a child theme of Sterling (a premium theme by True Theme)

Test results :

- Desactivate plugins : no effet
- Activate parent theme : no effet
- Activate another basic theme : solves the problem
- Logs : no error
- I have another site using the same theme and the same plugins, wp version and so on : no problem

Weird ...

Any Idea of what could cause this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer (True theme support helped me to find it):
There is an "notify updates" option that contacts their server every time you load an admin page. It wastes a lot of time. 
Now, the page loads in 3 sec.